# bundle.js loads very slow

Tags: node.js, express

I am using ec2(nodejs+express+webpack)-cloudflare setup and my bundle size is only about 100kb.

But the problem is that the 100kb bundle takes way too long(25~30secs)

I think it is a problem in my express or nodejs setting since index.html[1kb] also takes 700ms and favicon[2kb] takes 1.91s to load.

I'm wondering if this is because ec2 freetier is slow or is it my setting that's keeping it so slow.

I use

1 cloudflare ssl for https connection

2 iptables prerouting from 80 to 3000(my node env)

3 express server with main page like this

```
const app = express();
const port = process.env.p || 3000;

app.get('/', function (request, response){
    response.sendFile(path.resolve('public', 'index.html'), 'utf8');

});
app.use('/css', express.static('css'));
app.use('/static', express.static('static'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/signup', (req, res) =>{
    signup(req.body, res);
});
app.post('/login', (req, res) =>{
    login(req.body, res);
});
app.get('/userlist', (req, res)=>{
    ulist(req.query, res);
});
app.get('/atoc', (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.query);
    atocf(req.query, res);
});
app.get('/data/allshops', (req, res)=>{
    allshops(res);
});

app.get('/manager/checkurl', (req,res)=>{
    checkurl(req.query, res);
});
app.post('/manager/upload', upload.single('file'),(req,res)=>{
    s3u(req.file,req.body, res);
})
app.post('/manager/addshop', (req,res)=>{
    addshop(req.body, res);
});
app.post('/manager/editshop', (req,res)=>{
    editshop(req.body, res);
});
app.post('/manager/shop', (req,res)=>{
    mshopdata(req.body, res);
});
app.post('/manager/shops', (req,res)=>{
    myshops(req.body, res);
});
app.post('/manager/pub', (req,res)=>{
    msetpublic(req.body, res);
});
app.post('/manager/rm', (req,res)=>{
    msetrm(req.body, res);
});
app.post('/data/shop', (req,res)=>{
    if(req.body._url==undefined||req.body._url==''){
        res.send("{'ic_error':'NO_URL'}");
    }
    else
        shopdata(req.body, res);
});

app.get('*', function (request, response){

    const paths = request.path.split('/');
    if(nofollow.includes(paths[1])){
        response.sendFile(path.resolve('public', 'index.html'), 'utf8');
        return;
    }
    if(keypaths.includes(paths[1])){
        response.sendFile(path.resolve('public', paths[1]+'.html'),'utf8');
        return;
    }
    //shopmetadata({_url: decodeURIComponent(paths[1])}, response);
    sendpage({_url: decodeURIComponent(paths[1])},response)
});


const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Express listening on port', port);
});
```

What may I be doing wrong that is slowing down the traffic so hard?

thanks in advance!